# Access violation new c++ struct

Tags: c++, struct, visual-studio-2017, new-operator, access-violation

I have this struct:

```
struct event_ {

    bool is_crossover = false;
    bool is_birth = false;
    bool is_repetitive = false;

    int eID = 0;

    bool inicio_fin = false; 
    fecha inicio_fecha;
    fecha fin_fecha;

    locacion inicio_l;
    string eLatitud_i = 0; 
    string eLongitud_i = 0;

    locacion fin_l;
    string eLatitud_f = 0;
    string eLongitud_f = 0;

    personaje_info personajes_evento; //This is a class
    int cantidad_personajes = 0;

    string nombre;
    string descripcion;
    string tipo_evento;

    event_ *sig, *ant;
};
```

And then, when I call the function:

```
event_ *n = new event_;
```

it sends me an Access Violation Error:

```
Exception thrown at 0x0F69F6E0 (ucrtbased.dll) in Auxiliar Libros.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

Anyone knows why is this happening?
As additional information, I ran a Code Metrics Analysis, and before this, the program worked perfectly fine. And also it tells me about exceptions, what should I do?

Comment: Hmm... `string eLongitud_f = 0;` is giving me logic errors on gcc.

Comment: `Access violation reading location 0x00000000` means you're trying to dereference a null pointer somewhere. `event_ *n = new event_;` should not be able to cause this, unless you overloaded the `new` operator.

Comment: Actually, it is possible that your `personaje_info` class's constructor is trying to dereference a null pointer, so that would be a place to check

Comment: Replace all the `string xxx = 0;` with `string xxx;`

Comment: @shiosaku: welcome to StackOveflow. It is really a great Q&A site. I have a little remark about your question. I'm C++ programmer since 1986 and when I encounter same problem and that the code impacted is very short as your code. I don't contact directly StackOverflow. I try first to reduce my code. It is not easy to make that in comment, so I will propose an answer that is not an answer but only a way to find an answer.

Comment: I this program: `#include <iostream>

struct event_ {
        int test;
};

int main(){
 event_ *n = new event_;
        delete n;

        std::cout << "I am successful\n";
}` and it works fine on g++ 8.3 on Fedora 29. Would you like to provide the complete program that fails?

Comment: @Hemil Why? C++ is not Java, and `new` operator returns a pointer to an object (e.g. `event_ *`).

Comment: I don't get you @AlgirdasPreidžius

Comment: @Hemil Simpy put: `event_ n = new event_`, as you suggested, would fail to compile.

Comment: Yes it would. But i don't get your point

Comment: @Hemil I was responding to this comment, made by you: "It should be `event_ n = new event_` and not `event_ *n = new event_ i` feel". And, was responding to it, to point out, that it is wrong.

Comment: Oops. I have been doing Andoird lately ;P. Thanks for letting me know @AlgirdasPreidžius

Answer (score 1):

This code

```
string eLongitud_f = 0;
```

calls the string constructor with a NULL pointer (`0` is another way of writing the NULL pointer), resulting in your access validation error.

What do you think that code is doing? Obviously `0` is an integer not a `string`. Did you mean this?

```
string eLongitud_f = "0";
```

Or did you mean this?

```
string eLongitud_f = "";
```

Maybe you even meant this

```
double eLongitud_f = 0.0;
```

You can also just have this

```
string eLongitud_f;
```

which is the same as the second alternative above. All these are possible, it's hard to know which you really want, but the fundamental problem is that you are have a string variable and you are trying to give it a value which is not a string.

Comment: Oh wow! I didn't even know that an integer would be implicitly cast to a const char pointer for `std::string`'s assignment operator. I just assumed they used that as a placeholder for those strings. Or is it being cast to a character?

Comment: @JeffreyCash That only happens to the integer zero. Any other integer would be a compiler error. It's an unfortunate legacy, modern C++ has `nullptr` for the null pointer, but zero still stands for the null pointer too.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't even noted this... It's working now c:

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, I think that the best thing to do is to reduce your code and try some combinaison.

First, you must try a little `struct` with only one `bool` variable to see if your new function is correct

```
struct event_
    {
    bool is_crossover = false;
    };

event_ *n = new event_;
```

If your program continue to crash, your error is there, in new().

Else you can try then to reduce your structure removing what you think is correct.

Personnaly, I think that all your `bool`, `int` and `event_` declaration are correct, so I remove them.
I think that similar object declaraction can also be removed and I remove them.

I have following structure:

```
struct event_
    {
    fecha fin_fecha;
    locacion inicio_l;
    string eLatitud_i = 0; 
    personaje_info personajes_evento;
    };
```

What happens when you build and run this code ?

If you program has stopped to crash, the error is in removed code ?

Else, one (or more) declaration's line of this new structure is incorrect.

If changing your struct has too much impact in your code, your create a similar structure (other name not yet used) and you test it.

Please, can you try ? I think that you will find very quickly solve the problem yourself !

There are too much variables in your first code that can produce your crash ?